lock accessing to a property in C# using methods
I have the following class:
internal class Invite {
    private int _State = 0;

    public int State {
        get {
            // should be thread safe
            return _State;
        }
        set {
            _State = value;
        }
    }

    public void EnterUpdate() {
        // lock _state
    }

    public void ExitUpdate() {
        // release lock

    }
}

So when a thread wants to read the "State" it should be thread-safe however, there is also a possibility to lock that using a public methods an unlock it with another method.
var obInvite= new Invite();
obInvite.EnterUpdate();
// ....
obInvite.ExitUpdate();

Generally I want something like Transaction, but presence of "EnterUpdate" and "ExitUpdate" is important and only having "lock" around the "get" and "set" would not suffice for my requirement.
I have tried Mutex, Monitor or ReaderWriterLockSlim but they could not help, or either I could not use them properly.
Update:
I can give more context. At the same time a object of an Invite can be written to a third party service with a new State, it can be read in another thread from  the same third party service. So I would like to wait until it is committed and then let other threads read the State.

"but they could not help" - please explain how exactly you have checked and show some attempts.

Having Enter/exit methods like this can be quite dangerous. You would typically either keep the lock object private. Or let the caller manage locking. So what is the specific use case? Whenever you coordinate access to multiple resources you need to be super careful to avoid deadlocks.

Reading or writting an int is atomic, so it's always thread-safe. What do you really want to lock?

Some notes. 1) reading and  writing int is an atomic operation by itself (i.e. no need to lock here, unless you are reading and then writing updated value or something similar) 2) EnterUpdate should better return a disposable (or use try-finally), so ExitUpdate is called even if error is thrown mid-update. 3) if update involves async operations Monitor/Mutex should not be used.

If I understand correctly, you need something like "update this int only if some other operation succeeded but make the result (any changes made) readable at once or not at all"? Maybe it's worthwhile to construct a [mre] of what you are trying to do?

Without understanding any more detail it might be worth considering public IDisposable EnterUpdate() and simply use using (EnterUpdate()) { ... } (whereby the Dispose() automatically does the ExitUpdate code.)
